# Unable to build C++/CLI app using VS 2010, .Net 3.5, and 64-bit

Tags: visual-studio-2010, .net-3.5, c++-cli, 32bit-64bit

I have a C++/CLI app that is built under Visual Studio 2010 but using .Net 3.5.  As required, I hand edited my project file to add the TargetFrameworkVersion with a value of 3.5 and was able to build it without issue when I was in x86 (32-bit) mode.  However, when I switched to build it in x64 (64-bit) mode, I got the following error:

error MSB8014: Execution path (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\bin\x86_amd64) could not be found.

I do have VS 2008 (9.0) installed, but there is no x86_amd64 directory under the bin folder.  I tried fooling it by adding this folder (and the amd64 folder which would have failed thanks to the next line in the targets file), and then I got the error:

fatal error LNK1112: module machine type 'X86' conflicts with target machine type 'x64'

which I can't figure out because my project has no explicit links.  I switched the C# assemblies that it interacts with to build in x64 (as opposed to any CPU) but to no avail.

FYI: Everything builds correctly in 32-bit mode.  Everything also build correctly in 64 bit mode if I switch to .Net 4.0 (v100).  I get the same errors building in both release and debug mode.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: What bitness is your build OS?

Comment: OS is Windows 7 - 64 bit

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you are compiling with the "toolset" changed over from V100 to V90 on the project properties, and you have Visual Studio 2008 installed on the same development machine, just go to Control Panel, Programs and Features, select Visual Studio 2008, right-click, select Uninstall/Change, then select to add/remove f eatures, then when you are presented with a list of features, look for x64 compiler/files under Visual C++ which is not installed by default,but by clicking on the checkbox next to it, it will add the needed files.

Comment: It sucks. Why couldn't they keep it enabled by default when hell lot of other components were being installed. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: This only seems to be a solution with VS 2008 Standard or above. The Visual C++ 2008 Express installer does not seem to have such an option.

Answer (score 5):

In VS2010 it should link to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin\x86_amd64`

You probably got configuration wrong, or imported from a vs2008 project.

Go to **`Configuration -> General -> Platform Toolset`**. make sure it's **`v100`** (vs2010)

If that doesn't help , look at **`Configuration -> VC++ Directories`**. That's where that path is set.
You can see that it looks in **`$(VCInstallDir)`** which in your computer is set to the VS2008 path.